# Polynomial Interpolation and Error

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

I have numerical analysis final coming up in a few weeks and I'm trying to tackle a practice exam.

Assuming $p(x)$ interpolates the function $f(x)$, find the polynomial $p(x)$ that satisfies the following conditions:
$$p(0) = 20, p(1) = 26, p'(1)=9, p(2) = 36, p'(2)=16$$.

I also have to provide an expression for the interpolation error.

I've been going through my book and notes all afternoon, but I'm afraid I just don't understand.

Comment: I think that this involves Hermite Interpolation, so I'm reading up on that now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are given five conditions, your polynomial must be at least of degree 4. So, write
$$p(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4  $$
Establish the derivative $p'(x)$. Apply all given conditions. You have now a system of five linear equations for five unknowns $(a,b,c,d,e)$. Just solve it (the solutions are simple). This will give you the solution to the first part of your problem.

Comment: (Hope the introduction of Latex-format is not unwelcome...)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms. Thanks for editing my answer. My problem is that I am almost blind and I have major trouble as soon as I have to type anything else than pure ASCII. Ages are not making things easier. Cheers.

Comment: Suffering from weak health too, I think I'm only a couple of years away from the same. So - ... shake hands for a while to share life ...:)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms. Yes, let us shake hands and hope ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici are you familiar with solving this without the use of a 5 x 5 system?

Comment: @Neurax. The system of equations is so simple that you can eliminate one variable at the time. You will end with one linear equation for one unknown. Then, back substitute to get the other parameters.

Comment: @Neurax. I give you below the way of getting the function in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As asked by Neurax, i describe the way of getting the function without using matrix for the 5x5 system.

I keep the notation used on my previous answer and I use the conditions in the order they appear in the initial post.

Equations then write

p(0) =  20   gives a = 20
p(1) =  26   gives a + b + c + d + e = 26
p'(1) =  9   gives b + 2 c + 3 b + 4 e = 9
p(2) =  36   gives a + 2 b + 4 c + 8 d + 16 e = 36
p'(2) = 16   gives b + 4 c + 12 d + 32 e = 16

Then the first equation gives simply a = 20. Replacing this value in the four next equations lead to
b + c + d + e = 6
b + 2 c + 3 d + 4 e = 9
2 b + 4 c + 8 d + 16 e = 16
b + 4 c + 12 d + 32 e = 16
Now, we eliminate b from what became the new first equation. This gives
b = 6 - c - d - e
and we inject this expression in the next three equations. This leads now to
c + 2 d + 3 e = 3
2 c + 6 d + 14 e = 4
3 c + 11 d + 31 e = 10
Now, we eliminate c from what became the new first equation. This gives
c = 3 - 2 d - 3 e
and we inject this expression in the next two equations. This leads now to
2 d + 8 e = -2
5 d + 22 e = 1

Now, we eliminate d from what became the new first equation. This gives
d = -4 e - 1
Injected in the remaining equation, we then have
2 e = 6
Now we are done and we shall back substitute : so e = 3 , d = -13, c = 20 , b = -4 and a = 20.